# Npm packages that used for proxy server

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, http-proxy

What the proxy server means here:

- A proxy server be used in HTTP_PROXY shell environment.
- A proxy server be used in https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/connection-settings-firefox
- A proxy server can handle the curl under here:

```
curl -vvv --proxy "http://localhost:8000" https://www.google.com
```

What the proxy server not means here:

- A proxy server forward request to specific server.
- middleware of express
- `mock server` in full stack development.

Why I have to make this problems here?
The search engine SEO makes the search result sucks.
The phrase `http proxy` is full of ambiguities.

If you know any packages that fulfill the requirements in this question, please share it.
The existence of this problem will make it faster for those who need it in the future to find a more complete and powerful package with more features.

There are some result I found.

- berstend/straightforward, imperfect, still some bugs.
- none